# enter text in a popup, cant find elements with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to get some text entered into the username and password boxes in a popup
https://fantasy.espn.com/football/players/add?leagueId=1

I assume that there is a popup so I believe Ive switched to it. Im not able to find any elements that I can select. I tried doing

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")`

or

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Username or Email Address']")`

Both times I'm getting the error stating element not found:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://fantasy.espn.com/football/players/add?leagueId=1")
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Username or Email Address']")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pop-up is loading within an `iframe`. You have to first [*switch to the iframe*](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames) and then find rest the fields using xpath or other selectors.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = Chrome('drivers/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://fantasy.espn.com/football/players/add?leagueId=1')
iframe_xpath = '//*[@id="disneyid-iframe"]'
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, iframe_xpath)
    )
)
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
username_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']")
password_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']")
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="did-ui-view"]/div/section/section/form/section/div[3]/button'
) 
username_field.send_keys('username')
password_field .send_keys('password')
login_button.click()
```

**Edit**

Searching for players

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = Chrome('drivers/chromedriver', desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('https://fantasy.espn.com/football/leaders')
player_xpath = '//*[@id="espn-analytics"]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/input'
player_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, player_xpath)
    )
)
player_input.send_keys('chris\n')
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense, the way I was trying to switch to the iframe was incorrect. After you give the click command it goes to the page as it should. On this page there is a text box that I want to enter in information. Im not seeing any elements that are of use
<input placeholder="Player Name" class="form__control" value="">
class="form__control" value="">
I tried
time.sleep(20)
player = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Player Name']")
Is there another way I should look at doing this?

Comment: Thanks, Ive been tying to find out by searching, but am having no luck
How are you finding the indexs?
/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/input
how are you finding [5],[2],[1] etc?
I found tools that will show me the absolute path, but that is from the root. It seems like you are starting at the espn-analytics section

Comment: @encore02 You can get them from chrome Dev tools. Inspect the element -> right click -> copy -> copy xpath

Comment: This is great info, I was looking at other tools in order to find the xpath. My goal was to put this into one single script. What I noticed my problem was, was not that my xpath was incorrect, but after logging in I had to change to the default iframe. From your 2nd script you are able to enter a player name and you will get a drop down of a list of players (if you remove \n). The issue is I can issue a command to send the down arrow, but it looks like it wants a mouse click on the name to select the player. Sending enter does not work. I need to find a way to move the mouse over the name+clik